# Cómo guardar en una tabla un array XML de otro XML en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

tengo este xml:

```
    <SiniestrosGestionados>
  <SiniestroGestionado Siniestro="2713652 (O), 2713653 (R), 2713654 (R), 2713655 (R)" TipoContingencia="Enfermedad Profesional" DniAccidentado="24.072.747" NombreAccidentado="Gerónimo Rodríguez" ImporteSolicitado="$ 32.240,00" MontoLiquidado="$ 0,00" DiferenciaReclamadoLiquidado="$ 32.240,00" DiasLiquidados="25" PeriodosLiquidados="OCT-2021">
    <Diferencias>
      <Diferencia MotivoDiferencia="Falta recibo de sueldo" PeriodosRechazados="SEP-2017, JUL-2017,AGO-2017" Observacion="Período/s: 07/2017, 08/2017 rechazado/s por motivo: Prescripción." />
      <Diferencia MotivoDiferencia="Período ya pagado" PeriodosRechazados="SEP-2017" Observacion="Período/s: 09/2017 rechazado/s por motivo: Prescripción. Ya se pasó el tiempo" />
    </Diferencias>
  </SiniestroGestionado>
<SiniestrosGestionados>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es guardar en una tabla los datos de on siniestroGestionado, cosa que ya hice acá:

```
DECLARE @dataXML XML = CAST( @stringPrueba AS XML);
        DECLARE @hdoc int
        

        EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @dataXML;

        SELECT Siniestro, TipoContingencia, DniAccidentado, NombreAccidentado, ImporteSolicitado, MontoLiquidado, DiferenciaReclamadoLiquidado, DiasLiquidados, PeriodosLiquidados, convert(varchar(max), Diferencias) as Diferencias
        INTO #tmpSiniestrosGestionados
        FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, 'SiniestrosGestionados/SiniestroGestionado/Diferencias')
        WITH 
        (
        Siniestro [VARCHAR](MAX) '../@Siniestro',
        TipoContingencia [VARCHAR](100) '../@TipoContingencia',
        DniAccidentado [VARCHAR](30) '../@DniAccidentado',
        NombreAccidentado VARCHAR(200) '../@NombreAccidentado',
        ImporteSolicitado VARCHAR(100)'../@ImporteSolicitado',
        MontoLiquidado VARCHAR(100) '../@MontoLiquidado',
        DiferenciaReclamadoLiquidado VARCHAR(100) '../@DiferenciaReclamadoLiquidado',
        DiasLiquidados VARCHAR(100) '../@DiasLiquidados',
        PeriodosLiquidados VARCHAR(MAX) '../@PeriodosLiquidados',       
        Diferencias varchar(max) 'Diferencias'
        )

        SELECT * FROM #tmpSiniestrosGestionados

        DROP TABLE #tmpSiniestrosGestionados
```

El tema, es que, necesito que la parte de:

```
<Diferencias>
      <Diferencia MotivoDiferencia="Falta recibo de sueldo" PeriodosRechazados="" Observacion="Falta documentación." />
    </Diferencias>
```

Se guarde en la columna diferencias, como un string, es decir, de la misma forma, ya que sera procesado luego por otro metodo... hay forma de hacer eso? a mi me queda null cuando lo ejecuto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta [Diferencias] varchar(max) as XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listo... lo saque... Perdon!! mala mia jaja... Lo dejo aca por si alguien tiene el mismo problema. Saludos!

```
        SELECT Siniestro, TipoContingencia, DniAccidentado, NombreAccidentado, ImporteSolicitado, MontoLiquidado, DiferenciaReclamadoLiquidado, DiasLiquidados, PeriodosLiquidados, Diferencias
    INTO #tmpSiniestrosGestionados
    FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, 'SiniestrosGestionados/SiniestroGestionado')
    WITH 
    (
    Siniestro [VARCHAR](MAX) '@Siniestro',
    TipoContingencia [VARCHAR](100) '@TipoContingencia',
    DniAccidentado [VARCHAR](30) '@DniAccidentado',
    NombreAccidentado VARCHAR(200) '@NombreAccidentado',
    ImporteSolicitado VARCHAR(100)'@ImporteSolicitado',
    MontoLiquidado VARCHAR(100) '@MontoLiquidado',
    DiferenciaReclamadoLiquidado VARCHAR(100) '@DiferenciaReclamadoLiquidado',
    DiasLiquidados VARCHAR(100) '@DiasLiquidados',
    PeriodosLiquidados VARCHAR(MAX) '@PeriodosLiquidados',      
    Diferencias xml 'Diferencias'
    )
```

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada dentro de 24 horas aprox. Esto ayudará a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D